# Image Augmentation not altering my images at all

Tags: tensorflow, image-processing, image-augmentation

I am trying to implement some image augmentation to my dataset of brain scan MRIs. I'm using the same code from the TensorFlow tutorial page, yet it does not seem to be augmenting my images at all:

```
    data_augmentation = keras.Sequential(
  [
    layers.RandomFlip("horizontal",
                      input_shape=(img_height,
                                  img_width,
                                  3)),
    layers.RandomRotation(0.1),
    layers.RandomZoom(0.1),
  ]
)


plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
for images, _ in train_ds.take(1):
  for i in range(9):
    augmented_images = data_augmentation(images)
    ax = plt.subplot(3, 3, i + 1)
    plt.imshow(augmented_images[0].numpy().astype("uint8"))
    plt.axis("off")
```

[Have run it several times but none of the images show any augmentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oi5y4.png)

Comment: Try `data_augmentation(images, training=True)`, those layers only active while training.

Comment: @Frightera Worked a charm. Thank you!